# Video embedded in Open Office Impress flickering

Tags: graphics, video, libreoffice, intel-graphics

I have an issue with an embedded .avi video on Open Office Impress. The source video itself plays normally in Xine, Videos, VLC.

When embedded in Impress, the video gets distorted by a flickering line (no matter if it was resized & repositioned or if it was embedded without resizing etc.).

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (64 bit) with an Intel Haswell graphics card, the drivers of which are updated as far as I am aware.

Any ideas on how to fix this? It seems to me to be an Impress issue and not a graphics card issue, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Or am I just using a video format + codec that Impress doesn't like? If so, what would be a good one to format the video to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same problem and still couldn't find a permanent solution but strangely, this problem is solved when you put the video box slightly on the up-left corner of the page. See the screenshot below.

[image]

And it doesn't do that flickering during the presentation! It saved my day. Thought it could help out even though it's not a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue.

Apparently there is a workaround to minimise flickering.

Go in Tools > Options > Libreoffice Impress > General and uncheck Use background cache

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-gtk3
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk2
```

gtk is a window toolkit to build graphical user interfaces. The lines above replace the gtk3 version (automatically used in ubuntu 18.04) by the more stable version 2 (as I understand it).

Answer (score 0):

Try simply installing the codecs using these 2 commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras    
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - unfortunately this didn't solve the problem... (even after running sudo apt-get update). I'd be grateful for any other ideas!